# Is it possible to do a conditional put or update in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Let's say that I am storing records with following structure in DynamoDB:

```
{    
    "id": "57cf5b43-f9ec-4796-9de6-6a50f556cfd8",
    "created_at": "2015-09-18T13:27:00+12:00",
    "count": 3
}
```

Now, is it possible to achieve the following in one request:

- if the record with given `id` doesn't exist it should be created with count = 1
- if the record for that `id` exists the counter is being updated.

Currently I'm doing a query to check if the record exist and depending on the result I do a `put` or an `update`. It would be nice to fold that into a single operation.

Comment: This wouldn't work if you also wanted to upsert `id`, if `id` were a key to your table. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30296850/is-it-possible-to-change-value-of-range-key-in-dynamodb-table#30314563 ... Useful for those who attempted to do what I just tried, by adapting your solution.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

What I didn't mention in my question was that I wanted the `count` go up for subsequent events without modifying the `created_at`.
My final working UpdateInput looks like that:

```
{
  Key: {
    id: {
      S: "some_unique_id"
    }
  },
  TableName: "test",
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    #t: "created_at",
    #c: "count"
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    :t: {
      S: "2015-09-26T15:58:57+12:00"
    },
    :c: {
      N: "1"
    }
  },
  UpdateExpression: "SET #t = if_not_exists(#t, :t) ADD #c :c"
}
```

Comment: This is perfect for an `upsert` operation.

Answer (score 28):

You can do this with [`UpdateItem`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html) API and the [`UpdateExpression`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#DDB-UpdateItem-request-UpdateExpression) because of your use case. Since `count` will be a `Number` type here, you can use the `SET` or `ADD` expressions:

The documentation for `ADD` tells you that you can use it for `Number` types (emphasis mine):

> - ADD - Adds the specified value to the item, if the attribute does not already exist. If the attribute does exist, then the behavior of ADD depends on the data type of the attribute:
>
>   - If the existing attribute is a number, and if *Value* is also a number, then *Value* is mathematically added to the existing attribute. If *Value* is a negative number, then it is subtracted from the existing attribute.
>
>   **If you use ADD to increment or decrement a number value for an item that doesn't exist before the update, DynamoDB uses 0 as the initial value.** Similarly, if you use ADD for an existing item to increment or decrement an attribute value that doesn't exist before the update, DynamoDB uses 0 as the initial value. For example, suppose that the item you want to update doesn't have an attribute named itemcount, but you decide to ADD the number 3 to this attribute anyway. DynamoDB will create the itemcount attribute, set its initial value to 0, and finally add 3 to it. The result will be a new itemcount attribute in the item, with a value of 3.

For your example, you could have your `UpdateExpression` be `ADD #c :n`, where `:n` has an [`ExpressionAttributeValue`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#DDB-UpdateItem-request-ExpressionAttributeValues) of the `Number` type, `1` is the value, and `#c` has the [`ExpressionAttributeName`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#DDB-UpdateItem-request-ExpressionAttributeNames) substitution for `count`. You need to use a placeholder for `count` because it is a [reserved word](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html).

See more examples on the [*Modifying Items and Attributes with Update Expressions*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Modifying.html)