# DynamoDb Java API - Insert if does not exist on counter increment

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to insert item if it does not exist and set its counter to 1 or increment counter by one when it exists but it doesn't seem to work...

Here is what I have done so far:

```
UpdateItemSpec updateItemSpec = new UpdateItemSpec()
    .withPrimaryKey("Id", Id)
    .withReturnValues(ReturnValue.ALL_NEW)
    .withUpdateExpression("set #c = if_not_exists(#c = :val, #c + :val)")
    .withNameMap(new NameMap()
        .with("#c", "counter"))
    .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
        .withNumber(":val", 1));
```

when I change the update expression to `set #c = #c + :val` it updates existing items but it doesn't insert new item if it does not exist.

`set #c = :val` seems to work on both exist and not exist but that's not what I need.

Comment: Found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32777374/is-it-possible-to-do-a-conditional-put-or-update-in-dynamodb

This is the right update expression ADD #c :val

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create and update the item with one UpdateItem call.
UpdateExpression would be `ADD #c :val` because DynamoDB pretends the value of a Number is zero in ADD operations on items that do not exist yet.

Comment: following the question, the above as code is: `.withUpdateExpression("ADD #c :val)")`